# Involved in or involved with

Tags: prepositions, phrases

there are two sentences:

> The HR department
>   will also be involved **with** training and professional development of the company's staff.
>
> A company's HR department may also be involved **in** making people redundant.

What's the difference between *involved in* and *involved with* in these two sentences?

Where should i use former and latter? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**involved (in sth)** usually means taking part in something; being part of something.

> He was not involved in the conspiracy.
>   I want to meet the person involved in this project.

A company's HR department may also be involved in making people redundant. It implies department is part of or takes part in the process of making people redundant.

**involved(with somebody/something)** means giving a lot of time or attention to somebody/something.

> She was deeply **involved with** the local hospital.
>   He has been **involved with** human rights for many years.

The HR department will also be involved with training and professional development of the company's staff. It implies the department will give a lot of attention to the development of the company's staff.